# How can I found out who upvoted me

Tags: support

I just checked my PPCG account (2 mins ago) and saw that on all of my answers, someone had upvoted them. I thought to myself "Great! +80 rep!". Then I thought "Who did this and how can I ask them why" given that all my answers were in my [new language](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/Valyrio) that so far no one really cares about.

That's why I'm asking "How can I find out who upvoted my answers?". Is this possible?

Comment: [Somewhat related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296108/view-voters-of-a-post) that I posted on the Stack Overflow Meta site (as you can see, not many people liked my suggestion...). The general reason is to prevent people from revenge-downvoting or upvoting (though that wouldn't be really an act of vengeance...). Also the comments on that question are kinda funny...

Comment: [Also an SE-META post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not. For better or worse, upvotes and downvotes are completely anonymous. Not even moderators can see who voted on which posts.

Heads-up: if these eight upvotes were cast in quick succession, there's a decent chance they'll get reversed by the system.

Comment: I have personal experience with the vote reversal, I upvoted 5 answers (or questions, I don't remember which) which I thought were very high-quality on the Mathematics SE site, but it turns out they were all by the same user so it got reversed. These upvotes are likely to have the same effect, unless they were all cast by different users. Even still, there's a chance they'll get reversed, so just be warned of that.

Comment: Thanks! Although now I'm anticipating my drop down to 60 rep. :(